# reference device -> develop DirectX11 on old hardware?

Tags: opengl, directx, hardware

I just read about the "reference device' device type in direct3D.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219625(v=vs.85).aspx

Does this mean I can develop and test (not performance, just visual result) a Direct3D 11 Application including fancy ShaderLevel5 stuff on any old hardware?

Is there an equivalent for OpenGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes effectively that IS what the reference driver does.  Specifically it is there so that hardware rendering can be compared against it.  If the hardware rendering does not equal the reference then this can indicate a driver bug (or an "optimisation").

To my knowledge there is no reference driver for OpenGL, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm just considering whether to use OpenGL or DirectX for a project. And as I'm on old hardware, then I guess this means OpenGL is out..

Comment: @Mat: You can use DX9 compatible hardware with DX11 which is nice.  However equally you could write an OpenGL1.1 app if you want.  If you want to use the newer features then you are probably better off using the WARP device and going the software rendering route.

Comment: does WARP support all Direct3D features? I want to write an application that makes use of the RWBuffer feature which requies ShaderLevel5 - I'm on DirectX 10.1 Hardware

Comment: @Mat: Right, when you said old hardware I was imagining early DX9 level not DX10.1!  WARP is only 10.1 level so you're only choice is to use the reference rasteriser (or buy a new card).  The reference rasteriser is INCREDIBLY slow though, it is not meant for doing any real coding on but it "should" work.

Comment: the software needs to compare each frame to a image currently comming from a raytracer which takes about 10 minutes to calculate it - so, being slow is not an issue :) thanks for the help - I'll give it a try. I'll wait with accepting your answer a bit, maybe someone can add something regarding OpenGL

Comment: @Goz: "You can use DX9 compatible hardware with DX11" You can use geometry shaders in opengl (that's OpenGL 4) even on winxp. You can't do same thing with DirectX - there's no DX10/DX11 support on winxp, so no advanced/geometry shaders. I liked DX9, but after that microsoft's move I decided to switch to OpenGL - it is supported on several operating systems, so there's less chance of me being locked out of new features because of somebody's stupid decision.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I can develop and test (not performance, just visual result) a Direct3D 11 Application including fancy ShaderLevel5 stuff on any old hardware?

Yes. However, you should expect absolutely horrible performance. You could get about 1 frame **per minute** for complex pixel shaders (directx 9 reference device), and it can take even longer than that. Needless to say, same shader could work in real-time with hardware acceleration. Reference device weren't made for performance, and if I remember correctly, DirectX SDK states (somewhere) that main purpose of reference device was to allow developers to see if their scene looks the way it should and there are no unexpected driver bugs.

Another problem is that if you're running winxp, there will be no DirectX 10 or 11, reference device or not.

> Is there an equivalent for OpenGL?

No. Closest thing is mesa3d, but it isn't OpenGL-certified. 1..2 years ago it could display very different picture when GLSL shaders were involved. It could also crash on shaders with flow control. I haven't used it since. however, when used without GLSL shaders, mesa3d was quite fast and comparable to OpenGL, and was significantly faster han reference device in DirectX 9.

Answer (score 0):

[Mesa3d](http://www.mesa3d.org/) has a software rasterizer.  They recently added GL 3.0 support.